# Cannot Empty Dropdown On Page Transitions Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am having an issue using a single page approach. When I move to my "filter page" I want to populate a list of applications via ajax i simulated the call here.

```
function populateList()
{
     $('#drpApplication').empty().listview('refresh');
     if (typeof cache["FilterCounter"] == "undefined") {

                    cache["FilterCounter"] = 1;
                }
        var listItem = "<option value=" + '\'' + '1' + '\'' + ">" + 'Name1' + "</option>";
      $('#drpApplication').append(listItem);
            var listItem2 = "<option value=" + '\'' + '2' + '\'' + ">" + 'Name2' + "</option>";
      $('#drpApplication').append(listItem2);
            var listItem3 = "<option value=" + '\'' + '3' + '\'' + ">" + 'Name3' + "</option>";
      $('#drpApplication').append(listItem3);


}
```

Clicking apply puts me to another page, then when I go back to the filter page the application list Appends a new set of data. Eventhough I tell it to empty the dropdown first. Also selecting an application in the dropdown is suppose to add the selection to another listview on the page

```
    $('#drpApplication').change(function () {

        $("#drpApplication option:selected").each(function () {
            var filterItemId = 'liApplicationName' + cache["FilterCounter"].toString();
            $('#lstApplicationList').append('<li value="' + $(this).val() + '" id="' + filterItemId + '"data-icon="delete"><a onclick="removeFilterItem(\'' + filterItemId + '\')">' + $(this).text() + '</a></li>').listview('refresh');
            cache["FilterCounter"] = cache["FilterCounter"] + 1;
        });

    }).change();
```

What happens on subsequent visits is when you select an application from the dropdown it puts 2 of the same entries in the listview on the second visit and 3 entries every 1 one selection on the 3rd visit to the page and so on.

It seems that the DOM is caching its contents or something and i cannot stop it?

I started a jfiddle for this but my function to populate the list isnt running. I just started using jfiddle so maybe I have the simulation setup incorrectly?

http://jsfiddle.net/D2gbq/27/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are emptying the selects, then refreshing the listview, and then appending the new options. You need to refresh the listview *after* you append the options in order to make them appear.

Try this:

```
function populateList()
{
  $('#lstApplicationList').empty();
  $('#drpApplication').empty();

  if (typeof cache["FilterCounter"] == "undefined") {
    cache["FilterCounter"] = 1;
  }
    var listItem = "<option value=" + '\'' + '1' + '\'' + ">" + 'Name1' + "</option>";
    $('#drpApplication').append(listItem);

    var listItem2 = "<option value=" + '\'' + '2' + '\'' + ">" + 'Name2' + "</option>";
    $('#drpApplication').append(listItem2);

    var listItem3 = "<option value=" + '\'' + '3' + '\'' + ">" + 'Name3' + "</option>";
    $('#drpApplication').append(listItem3);

    $('#lstApplicationList').listview('refresh');
    $('#drpApplication').listview('refresh');
}
```